# Problema con el estilo de citas: especifico "csl: apa.csl" pero tengo el mismo resultado que sin especificar

Tags: r, latex, style, r-markdown, yaml

estoy realizando un TFG y me piden que cite en APA.

Con el código `csl: apa.csl` en el YAML le ordeno que utilice el estilo APA. Sin embargo, si elimino esa línea de código, obtengo el mismo resultado en el PDF generado. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Quiero utilizar APA6 y no consigo el resultado que quiero :(

Bonus: estoy obteniendo el siguiente formato:
**Bunge, M. (1980), *Epistemología*, Siglo XXI, Madrid**

Cuando, en teoría, debería generarme la referencia de este modo:
Bunge, M. (1980). *Epistemología*. Siglo XXI: Madrid

Dejo la copia de mi YAML por si tuviera algún error:

```
---
title: El concepto de naturaleza humana en Karl Polanyi y la función política de los Derechos
blinded: 0
authors: 
  
- name: Alberto Baeza Vaz

  thanks: El autor agradece al Ministerio de Educación por la concesión de la Beca de colaboración con el Departamento de Ciencias Políticas y de la Administración de la Universidad de Granada para el curso 2020/2021.
  
  affiliation: Facultad de Ciencias Políticas y Sociología, Universidad de Granada
header-includes:
  - \renewcommand\refname{Referencias}
  - \renewcommand{\harvardurl}{\textbf{URL:} \url}
  - \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
keywords:
- Karl Polanyi
- naturaleza humana
- Derechos
- teoría política
abstract: |
  The text of your abstract.  200 or fewer words.
lang: es
papersize: a4
fontsize: 12
csl: apa7.csl
bibliography: bibtfg3.bib
output: rticles::asa_article
editor_options:
  toc: true
  markdown: 
    wrap: sentence
---
```

Answer (score 0):

Alberto, no tienes error en tu YAML. Sin embargo, tratando de reproducir tu problema, me di cuenta de algo: la plantilla de `rticles` que estas usando (`asa_article`) tiene su estilo propio y no acepta opciones como `csl` o `biblio-style` para definir un estilo de citas y referencias que quieras. El estilo está definido en el archivo `agsm.bst` que encuentras en la carpeta de `rticles` de tu librería de paquetes (en Windows, en mi caso en `C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rticles\rmarkdown\templates\asa\skeleton\agsm.bst`).

Estuve buscando soluciones pero no encontré, a menos que sepas cómo modificar el archivo `bst`. Si no es el caso, mi sugerencia es que no uses plantilla, que uses una plantilla que permita definir el estilo csl que quieras, o una que use APA por defecto, como `papaja` (información [acá](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/papaja/versions/0.1.0.9997)).

Por supuesto, si existen otras soluciones, me gustaría también conocerlas.